# Using libunwind for implementing exceptions

Tags: c, exception, stack-unwinding, libunwind

Working on a compiler, need some assistance understanding and working with libunwind. Here's what I have so far:

```c
#define UNW_LOCAL_ONLY
#include <libunwind.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef void *data_t;
typedef struct exception_stack_st *exception_stack_t;

struct exception_stack_st {
  unw_cursor_t catch_block;
  exception_stack_t prev;
};

/* PROTOTYPES */
void foo(void);
void bar(void);
void set_try(void);
void clear_try(void);
bool check_exception(void);
void throw_exception(data_t);
void print_backtrace();

/* GLOBALS */
exception_stack_t exception_stack = NULL;
data_t curr_exception = NULL;

int main(void) {
  foo();
}

void foo(void) {
  printf("In foo\n");
  set_try();
  if(check_exception()) {
    printf("EXCEPTION: %s\n", (char*)curr_exception);
    goto CATCH;
  }
  bar();
  printf("This should never run\n");
 CATCH:
  clear_try();
  printf("Leaving foo\n");
}

void bar(void) {
  printf("In bar\n");
  throw_exception("Throwing an exception in bar");
  printf("Leaving bar\n");
}

void set_try(void) {
  unw_cursor_t cursor;
  unw_context_t context;
  unw_word_t ip, offp;
  char buf[1024];
  unw_getcontext(&context);
  unw_init_local(&cursor, &context);
  unw_step(&cursor);
  unw_get_reg(&cursor, UNW_REG_IP, &ip);
  unw_get_proc_name(&cursor, buf, 1024, &offp);
  printf("%s+0x%lx  IP %lx\n", buf, offp, ip);

  exception_stack_t cb = malloc(sizeof(struct exception_stack_st));
  cb->catch_block = cursor;
  cb->prev = exception_stack;
  exception_stack = cb;
}

void clear_try(void) {
  if (exception_stack != NULL)
    exception_stack = exception_stack->prev;
  curr_exception = NULL;
}

void throw_exception(data_t exception) {
  unw_word_t ip, offp;
  char buf[1024];
  curr_exception = exception;
  unw_get_reg(&(exception_stack->catch_block), UNW_REG_IP, &ip);
  unw_get_proc_name(&(exception_stack->catch_block), buf, 1024, &offp);
  printf("%s+0x%lx  IP %lx\n", buf, offp, ip);
  unw_resume(&(exception_stack->catch_block));
  printf("PANIC: unw_resume returned.\n");
  exit(1);
}

bool check_exception(void) {
  return curr_exception != NULL;
}

void print_backtrace() {
  unw_cursor_t cursor;
  unw_context_t context;
  char buf[1024];
  unw_getcontext(&context);
  unw_init_local(&cursor, &context);
  printf("BACKTRACE:\n");
  while(unw_step(&cursor) > 0) {
    unw_get_proc_name(&cursor, buf, 1024, NULL);
    printf("%s\n", buf);
  }
}
```

Alright, this is already pretty messy, but some context might help justify the weird choices. What I would like to do is call `throw_exception` at any point down the call stack after calling `set_try` in `foo` in order to unwind the stack and restore the CPU state to right after the call to `set_try` but before the conditional. While this is currently just a small C program, I'm intending on using the general structure of these functions in a compiler that will generate the function calls necessary (similar to how exceptions are done in C++ using g++), which is why I have the labels+goto as a way to quickly mimic the assembly I would be generating. I've tried using libunwind's setjmp implementation, but it doesn't quite fit my use case well enough.

The issue I'm having has to do with where `unw_resume` resumes after unwinding the call stack. The `printf("This should never run\n")` seems to run every time no matter what. My understanding is that it should restore the stack and CPU state to whatever was stored when the call to `unw_getcontext` was made, and I think the state that gets stored is correct because the value of the IP register (or PC register, since this is x86_64) is exactly the same in the cursor when I call `set_try` and `throw_exception`. I've even jumped into gdb a number of times to look at the PC register right after the call to set_try and before the conditional, and it matched the printed output every time.

My questions are:

- Am I misunderstanding `unw_resume`?
- Do I need to be modifying the PC (UNW_REG_IP) register?
- Is there somewhere (aside from nongnu.org docs) else I can look to for help with libunwind?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "The issue I'm having has to do with ..." -- you forgot to describe the actual issue. You've described (somewhat) what you *expect* to happen, but what did *actually* happen?

Comment: Ok, I've updated the question. The issue is that the `printf("This line should never run\n") is run every time I execute the program, even though it should be skipped over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First the good news: after fixes, your program produces (what I assume expected) output:

```
./a.out
In foo
foo+0x31  IP 557615f273a1
In bar
foo+0x31  IP 557615f273a1
foo+0x31  IP 557615f273a1
EXCEPTION: Throwing an exception in bar
Leaving foo
```

Now the bad news: there are a few separate issues with your original program:

1. The context (machine state) that was used to initialize the cursor must *remain* valid for the duration for which the cursor is used. This is explicitly spelled out in the [unw_init_local man page](https://www.nongnu.org/libunwind/man/unw_init_local(3).html).

   Violation of this rule caused your program to SIGSEGV on my machine during the `unw_resume` call.
2. The `unw_step` updates the *cursor*, but not the context, and it is the latter that is actually used to restore machine state in `unw_resume`.

   This could be made clearer in the [unw_resume documentation](https://www.nongnu.org/libunwind/man/unw_resume(3).html).

To fix problem 1, simply move `unw_context_t` into `exception_stack_st` like so:

```
struct exception_stack_st {
  unw_context_t context;
  unw_cursor_t cursor;
  exception_stack_t prev;
};
```

And initialize them together:

```
  exception_stack_t cb = malloc(sizeof(*cb));
  unw_getcontext(&cb->context);
  unw_init_local(&cb->cursor, &cb->context);
```

To fix problem 2, you need to establish the machine context *in the frame to which you intend to return*.

That requires either turning `set_try` into a macro, or an always inlined function, and getting rid of the `unw_step`.

Comment: Excellent! I'll give this a shot, thank you so much!